# Is it possible to check if std::promise result has already been set?

Tags: c++, std

In a C++ program I need to use a C library that receives a callback and calls it from a background thread whenever a certain event happens. In that callback I use a promise to notify the main thread of my program when I have the result I want, so the main thread waits on the future, gets the result and uses a function from the C library to unsubscribe/remove the callback so it's no longer called.

The problem however is that in some circumstances, after I set the promise value, the callback might get called again before the main thread is able to unsubscribe from the event, throwing a std::future_error when it tries to call set_value.

Obviously I could just add boolean flag local to the callback to keep track of whether the result has already been set or not, but that seems error prone in case the code needs to be changed again in the future. At least as far as c++20 there doesn't seem to exist a try_set_value method, I could implement one that catches the future_error and returns false but I'd rather avoid causing an exception to be thrown if it's not needed.

Which brings me back to the title, is it possible to check if a promise already has a result set, aside from calling set_value and catching the error?

Comment: *before the main thread is able to unsubscribe from the event* Do it in the callback. This is even more safe and does not require a critical section.

Comment: Fair enough. Access to the C lib is done through a wrapper class that is not available at the point the callback is defined, so it would require a bit of an annoying refactor in my case, but you're right, that is a good way to fix the issue.

Comment: Sounds like you have a race condition.  Focus on that, rather than trying to hack around it.

Comment: Don't make baseless assumptions, there is no race condition. Only one thread sets the result, only one thread waits on it. Once the result is set it can't change. The callback can't be called multiple times concurrently, an error occurs when it is executed sequentially two times in quick succession, setting the same result in both occasions.

Comment: Instead of a boolean flag, you could also wrap the body of your callback in a `std::call_once`, which seems less bug-prone and easier to read